# ¿Es "no ... más" como "ya no" correcto?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Existe algún criterio para la substitución de *ya no...* por *no ... más*?

Por ejemplo, la siguiente frase me parece correcta

> No bebo más  (significando *ya no bebo*).

Pero

> No es más problema / problemático.

**no** parece ser lo mismo que

> Ya no es un problema / problemático (correcto)

e incluso me parece incorrecto. ¿Es en alguna parte del mundo correcto?

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa es que "más" se puede confundir con adverbio de cantidad.

"No bebo más" puede significar que sí bebes, pero no en mayor cantidad, mientras que "Ya no bebo" sólo puede significar que no bebes, pero sí bebías en el pasado.

Lo mismo con "No es más problemático". Parece que te estás refiriendo a *qué tan problemático* es algo (no más que alguna otra cosa), en vez de a *cuándo fue problemático* algo (en el pasado, pero no ahora).

Mientras no haya ambigüedad con el otro significado de "más", se puede usar la construcción "no... más" sin más problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Como en muchos casos puede haber diferencias regionales pero todas son correctas.

En Colombia es absolutamente normal decir "Ya no es problema" o "Ya no es un problema" pero es muy raro decir "No es más un problema"

En el caso de "No bebo más" la usaría a eso de las 3 de la mañana al final de la fiesta para decir que ya he bebido lo suficiente por esta vez, mientras que al decir "ya no bebo" el sentido sería que en alguna época me gustaba beber pero ahora ya no lo hago.